# I need help identifying a vintage battery

Tags: batteries, sensor, identification, vintage

I found what looks like an old battery in the middle of nowhere. The plates are thick and soldered by hand. There is a matting between the plates like an AGM or maybe nickel iron battery. It's housed in some kind of clear green plastic that's not sealed and has some holes even. Perhaps it isn't a battery but some kind of sensor? I haven't a clue, honestly.[image]

Comment: I would not be touching that with bare hands

Comment: I first thought of a load resistor, but then it wouldn't be placed in a plastic sealing, because it's expected to get hot.

Comment: I'd be surprised if it was a battery without any obvious polarisation for the connections.

Comment: Especially since this may very well not be a battery, you might want to try r/whatisthisthing on Reddit.  They identify a wide variety of objects.

Comment: Mystery solved! It's a 1940s US Signal Corps weather balloon battery. Credit goes to Cyberdragn on eevblog. https://www.ebid.net/uk/for-sale/36v-battery-ready-for-use-lead-acid-bb-52-bb52-us-army-1946-radiosonde-ml-128-150323075.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mystery solved! It's a 1940s US Signal Corps weather balloon battery. Credit goes to Cyberdragon on eevblog:

https://www.ebid.net/uk/for-sale/36v-battery-ready-for-use-lead-acid-bb-52-bb52-us-army-1946-radiosonde-ml-128-150323075.htm